# An Image Alignment Issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, image

I have the following code:

```css
.aligned {
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
}

.p {
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.35em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
  color: #383838;
}

blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

blockquote cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \2009";
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  img {
    float: left;
    height: 200px; /* image height for larger screen only */
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" width="370" height="500">
<div class="aligned">
  <div class="p">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <blockquote>
      Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
      <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
    </blockquote>

  </div>
```

So when you run the above code, open it on a new page, you can see the alignment to be messed up

---

That is what my output looks like when I **zoom out**. I do not want that, is there a way to make it static, meaning even if I zoom out, the output of the above code I sent does not change?

Even if you run the above code, open it on a new page, and zoom out, you can see the text and the image to change its position. However, I want them to be static, meaning not change at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: @hossainomer did you try using media query https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp ?

Comment: Media query is already been used to make it responsive, how would I use it to make the image + text static and not change when zoomed out?

Comment: on media query: if screen width more than X then container width should be 100px(e.g.) makes sense? By container width mean div containing text and image

Comment: Can you show me?

Comment: I'm not noticing the difference in alignments. Can you help clarify?

Comment: When you run the above code, open it in a new page, and zoom out, you can see how the text + image changes their position. I don't want that, I just want them to stay static

Comment: @HussainOmer why do you add media queries then??

Comment: I added a media query to make it responsive, like when the device change its width and height. I don't see how adding a media query will help here since the problem only occurs after zooming out, the height of the device+width does not change. Maybe I am wrong, please show me if you have a suggestion

Comment: Check this out: https://codepen.io/saularis/pen/KKmdLja 

Play around with the width

Comment: That does not help. The text changes when zoomed out, which is not what I want. I want it to be static.

Comment: You could use units like "vh" or "vw" instead of "px" to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to keep both (image and text) in new div and make new div max width in maximum number so new code will be like

```
<div class="newdivcontainer">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" width="370" height="500">
<div class="aligned">
  <div class="p">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <blockquote>
      Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
      <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
    </blockquote>

  </div>
 

</div>
</div>
```

and css for the new div will be

```
.newdivcontainer {
max-width:100%;
width:960px;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

also make sure inner divs and p tags max width should be 100%; I ma expecting your site is responsive so above code will work fine.